# Integration of a function and its inverse

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $g(x)$ be the inverse function of the function $f(x)$ where
$x\in [a,b], f(a) = c, f(b) = d$.
Find the value of
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx  - \int_{c}^{d} g(y) dy$$
My turn:
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = F(b) -F(a)$$ where $F'(x) = f(x)$. And
$$\int_{c}^{d} g(y) dy = G(d) - G(c) = G(f(b)) - G(f(a))$$
where $G'(y) = g(y)$.
But I did not find a relation between the anti-derivative of f and the anti-derivative of its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, let's consider a special case: $f: [0,b] \to [0,d]$ increasing, continuous, onto. If you draw a picture then you realize that the first integral is the area of the rectangle $R:=[0,b] \times [0,d]$ under the graph of $f$ and the second integral is the area of $R$ above the graph - that's because the graph of the inverse is symmetrical about the diagonal and the second integral is the area under this graph. But if you reflect it around the diagonal, you get the graph of the original $f$ and you count the area "to the left" from it.

- So if you add them together, not subtract, then you get the area of
  $R$, i.e. $bd$. In general situation, you have to take into account
  more rectangles but it should be easily deducible from the picture of
  the situation.
- In your case, when you subtract the second integral from the first one, you can get pretty much everything
  between $-bd$ and $bd$. Just consider functions $x^n$ and inverses
  $\sqrt[n]{x}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Do you it does not have a certain answer ?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, take e.g. $f(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$, then its inverse is $g(y) = \sqrt[n]{y}$ on $[0,1]$, and we have $\int_{0}^{1} x^n \, dx  - \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[n]{y} \, dy = 2/n -1$.